# SQL Query to display if two dates is not bigger than a specified date

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

How can I select data that bigger than specified date (last requested date) and exclude if both created_at AND deleted_at is bigger than a specified date?

For example the last_requested_date is '2017-03-09 15:41:00'.
Then, I want to show country that are created/updated/deleted after '2017-03-09 15:41:00'. But I don't want to show country who has been created and then deleted after the last_requested_date (example created_at '2017-03-09 15:41:01' and deleted_at '2017-03-09 15:41:02')

My code is like:

```
SELECT * FROM countries
WHERE (created_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00' OR
      updated_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00' OR
      deleted_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00') AND
      NOT (created_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00' AND deleted_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00')
```

But the output is not was I expected. Any solution will be appreciate! Thank you

Comment: Your current logic makes no sense.  Can you include some sample data?  Even if you get an answer, your question won't be very helpful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM countries
 WHERE (created_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00' OR
  updated_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00' OR
  deleted_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00') AND id NOT IN
  (SELECT id FROM countries where created_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00' AND deleted_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00')
```

Comment: Actually I want to get query that not using sub-query. But this will do! Thank you!

Comment: `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` usually performs _terribly_, but it can usually be turned into `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
        SELECT * FROM countries
        WHERE (created_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00' OR
              updated_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00' OR
              deleted_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00') AND

        datediff(SECOND,created_at, deleted_at) > 60
```

Here we checking the difference between two dates (created_at and deleted_at) must be greater than 60 seconds, You can edit it is as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understoond you requirment correctly, then your query is very close to produce desire result. you may need to add just one more condition to check date diffrence between created date and deleted date to avoid countries which are created and deleted today it self.

```
SELECT * 
FROM countries
WHERE (created_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00' OR
       updated_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00' OR
       deleted_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00'
      ) AND (created_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00' AND 
             deleted_at > '2017-03-09 15:41:00' AND 
             DATEDIFF(created_at,deleted_at) > 0)
```